# Error while importing LXML

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, python-import, importerror

I was importing "from docx import Document".
This gave an error

> File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx.py", line 17, in 
>       *from lxml import etree* ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.7.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.so:
>   undefined symbol: gcry_check_version

Same error I am getting while trying to install `lxml`.

Python Version: 2.7, OS: `CentOS` release 5.8

Comment: It's possible you might be missing `libgcrypt`. Try doing `yum install libgcrypt libgcrypt-devel` and try again.

Comment: @zedfoxus : Running this is giving me this error : https://justpaste.it/11kcq

Comment: @zedfoxus : The error was too big to be pasted here. So I have shared the link with the error

Comment: Try doing `yum clean all` and then `yum clean metadata`. Then try to install libgcrypt and libgcrypt-devel.

Comment: @zedfoxus : Getting a diff error now : https://justpaste.it/11kd1

Comment: Can you paste the content of /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo file?

Comment: @zedfoxus : [rpmforge]
name=RPMFORGE
mirrorlist=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
protect=0

Comment: Make a copy of that file. Can you change `mirrorlist=apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge`  to `mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el6/mirrors-rpmforge` and save the file? Then try doing `yum clean all`, then `yum clean metadata`, then `yum update` and then install libgcrypt

Comment: @zedfoxus : Yum update is giving this error : https://justpaste.it/11ke7

Comment: That was my bad. You are using centos 5, so let's use `mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el5/mirrors-rpmfo‌​rge` instead. Notice that I've used `el5` instead of `el6`. Then the other commands.

Comment: @zedfoxus : yum update is still giving errors. The result of yum update is here : https://justpaste.it/11kel

Comment: Did `yum clean all` and `yum clean metadata` work just fine?

Comment: @zedfoxus : Yes it worked fine. [root@sweet-vtb01 ]# **yum clean all**
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@sweet-vtb01 ]# **yum clean metadata**
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
0 metadata files removed
0 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed

Comment: How many files do you have in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` - can you list them please?

Comment: The files are listed here : https://justpaste.it/11kfi

Comment: Do you have the ability to join this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131010/so41235484? If so, we can continue discussion there

Comment: @zedfoxus : Exporting libcrypt solved the issue..Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that a good answer helped you resolve your immediate issue. It might be worth the time, perhaps at a later time, to evaluate your repositories and fixing them so that you can install packages without issues.

Comment: @zedfoxus : Yes I would definitely fix it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libcrypt Issue

Try:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libgcrypt.so
export LD_PRELOAD
```

This should fix it